# How to test function depended on another one in python

Tags: pytest, python-unittest

I need to test this type of code bellow:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]

def getData(list):
    return list[0] + list[1]

def processData():
    data = getData(list)    
    multiply = data*data
    return multiply

def test_functions():
    assert getData([0,1]) == 1
    assert processData() == 1
```

How to tell the test I need data = getData([0,1]), so basically replace data with my test values.

Comment: Make it an actual argument?

Comment: def processData() dont expect any arguments

Comment: Yes, I can see that, and *that's the problem*. This is why you avoid global state.

Comment: so what is your proposal? Can you change the test code to work please? I need some workling example of this kind of testing (I am totally new in this stuff) :)

Comment: My proposal is to make it an argument, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587207/how-to-test-function-depended-on-another-one-in-python?noredirect=1#comment107187905_60587207. You can't *just* change the test code to work, because the code isn't written with testability in mind to start with. If you could directly test `processData([0, 1])`, then `getData` would become an implementation detail.